# Setting table captions when using SQLContainer

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using `Vaadin 7`.
In my simple scenario I would like to use a `Table` component with an `SQLContainer`.

The problem is that since `SQLContainer` does not implement `addContainerProperty` method (which would normally be used to set up column captions) I have no idea how to set captions for my SQLs.

Could somebody give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used SQLContainer, but addContainerProperty() is not the way to set caption, it's more key than caption (in my opinion).
You can use:

```
Table myTable = getMyTable();
myTable.setColumnHeader("header-key", "Header Caption");
```

Hope it helps